# Firestore orderBy query not returning expected results

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

When returning an orderBy query with multiple 'where' filters, i'm not receiving the expected results.

```
    try {
      const mvResults = this.afs.collection(`leader_board`, ref => ref
        .where('year', '>=', '1990')
        .where('event', '==', 'WAVUST')
        .where('body', 'in', ['Panelvan', 'SM Van', 'XL Van'])
        .orderBy('year')
        .orderBy('total', 'desc')
        .limit(10)).valueChanges()

        this.topModVan$ = mvResults.subscribe(data => {
        this.topModernVanDS = new MatTableDataSource(data);
        console.log('Top Modern Van: ' + JSON.stringify(data));
        
      })

    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Top Modern Van Error: ' + error.message);
      
    }
```

In the above code, I expect to get the highest returned 'total' field value first. What I am getting is a random pattern.

[image: Query Reslults]

Ultimately I only want to show the top 1 result (judging at a car show). You can see in the image HSVVAN should be the top, but it is way down the list.

I am expecting the document with the highest 'total' field value would be return in a query with limit(1) is applied.

Comment: I can get the desired result by increasing the year filter to 2000, but that excludes a heap of records that may be eligible.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is *first* ordered by `year` and only then by `total`, which means that the `total` value is only taken into consideration for documents where `year` has the same value.

Unfortunately there's no way to swap the ordering clauses, as you need `year` first because of the `.where('year', '>=', '1990')` condition.

The only solution is to reorder the results in your application code on `total` (first, or only).

Comment: Hi Frank,
Thanks for your input. The particular category that this query relates to is for vehicles built beyond 1990, so unfortunately the year has to stay.

I did get a bit of a result by changing the filter to start in the year 2000. By doing that I get the result I was after. 

Doing it that way, I exclude any vehicles built between 1990 and 1999. Not ideal, but the result is accurate.

Comment: Is it possible to create two queries, one selecting all records equal to or greater than 1990, then run a separate query against that result for the highest total and limit To(1)?

Comment: Not likely. You could pass the document IDs of the first query to the second one, but that only works up to 30 values. Is reordering the results in your application code that much of a problem that it's worth considering this?

Comment: It is in this instance. It's a car show judging app and some of the results are picking a car with a much lower total score than the vehicle that should win. Wierd thing is, the chosen vehicle is about 6 from the bottom with a score of 60, and the top vehicle has a score over 200. I will keep plugging away...